# Laravel Ubuntu server deployment

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu-16.04, web-deployment

I have a project in Laravel which I want to deploy it in my new Ubuntu 16.4 server.
I have installed all the needed packages and my project is working fine inside the server.

At first it was accessible from --> "IP-Address/project-name/public/index.php" then I made some changes in "/etc/apache2/sites-availabe/000-default.conf" as :

```html
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/panel/public/
        <Directory /var/www/html/panel>"
          AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

"panel" is the name of my project in Laravel. 
So now I can access my project from "http://IP-Address" but since the project has 2 parts as front and admin panel, i want to access the project in a URL like 
"IP-Address/" for javascript web part and "IP-address/panel" for the admin panel developed with Laravel.

Comment: Why you don't use router groups?

Comment: You mean router component inside the PHP code ?

Answer (score 0):

My Apache's configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Laravel's project is under `/var/www/html` directory.

To have another part of your application (for example admin panel under `/admin` path) you should use Laravel's router groups. Here you have [link to documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups).

Example from documentation

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

If you want `/panel` prefix just change `admin` into `panel`. All routes for panel declare in this group.